# Need Reference calculus problems book

Tags: calculus, soft-question, big-list

I research problems book in calculus/analysis(series/sequences and integrals) the subject is only technique/good problems.I give you some sample that i found.(sorry for the language):

- Exercices in Analysis;Gasinski
- Limits,Series and Fractionnal part    integral;Furdui,Cornel
- Calculus;Apostol
- Integral Calculus;Agarwal
- Handbook of applied Analysis;Nikolaos
- Irresistible Integral;Boros
- Theory and application of infinite series;Konrad Knopp
- Inside    interesting integral;Nahin
- kaczor
- Shakarichi
- Polya
- A treatise on    integral calculus;Joseph Edwards
- Problems in Analysis;Demidovich

Comment: You may be interested in *Irresistible Integrals* By George Boros and Victor Moll